# rspec - how to add more info to the Failure/Error where it occurs

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to output a bunch of information from the test if it fails.

When i puts out the information however it appears *before* the `Failures:` section of the rspec output as opposed to where the specific spec failure info is (line number etc)

Is there a way in rspec for the spec to show the info in the failure itself rather than separately?

I thought mybe an around hook, but...

> WARNING: around hooks do not share state with the example the way
>   before and after hooks do. This means that you cannot share instance
>   variables between around hooks and examples.```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a lambda in your test:

```
  expect(page).to have_text("Doesn't exist"), lambda { "This failed for all sorts of reasons, let me list them out here: #{detailed info}." }
```

Will give you output like:

```
    Failures:
  1) Blah blah blah
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text("Doesn't exist"), lambda { "This failed for all sorts of reasons, let me list them out here: nil." }
       This failed for all sorts of reasons, let me list them.
     # ./spec/features/search_results_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It can be a bit tricky if you have code like `expect(x).to eq y.count` as just tacking on the lambda gives 2 params given but 0..1 expected. to get around this use formats like

```
expect(x).to (eq y.count), lambda { "message" }
```

Comment: Yes, nice.  I can also refer to the spec's variaboles, so this is great